# Access custom coroutine context element inside coroutine job

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When user types in `EditText` I start a coroutine to search data from backend. I also want to cancel any existing search `Job`s. My understanding was that if I place a context object in `launch()` I will be able to access it later but it seems like `job[JobType]` always returns `null` for me.

Am I misunderstanding something here? Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val jobs = CopyOnWriteArrayList<Job>()

    sealed class JobType() : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(JobType) {
        companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<JobType>

        object SearchJob : JobType()
        object OtherJob : JobType()
    }

    fun search(query: String) = viewModelScope.launch(JobType.SearchJob) {
         //coroutineContext[JobType] gives JobType.SearchJob
         //but following doesn't work because job[JobType] is always null

         jobs.filter { it[JobType] == JobType.SearchJob }
                            .forEach { if (it != this) it.cancel() }
        //search online
    }.also {
        track(it)
    }

    private fun track(job: Job) {
        jobs.add(job)
        job.invokeOnCompletion {
            jobs.remove(job)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The coroutine context of your search job has a `Job` and a `JobType`. So if you look inside `Job` you won't find `JobType`, you'll have to look inside the context that `Job` is in. Basically go one level up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only call `search` on the main thread.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var searchJob: Job? = null

    fun search(query: String): Job {
        searchJob?.cancel()
        searchJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            //search online
        }
        return searchJob
    }
}
```